# How can one use WSL via VS by installing Ubuntu with error-0x80370102 even though the machine already runs a VM without issue?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio, wsl2

I am running Win 10 Home and I'm trying to install Ubuntu WSL 22.xx LTS (...something like that) through Visual Studio.

After downloading from the Windows Store a popup windows says it's installing and unpacking the distro, stating:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...

WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102

Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization

Press any key to continue...
```

So I clicked the link which brought me to the following page...

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#error-0x80370102-the-virtual-machine-could-not-be-started-because-a-required-feature-is-not-installed

1. Check the Hyper-V system requirements
2. If your machine is a VM, please enable nested virtualization manually. Launch PowerShell with admin, and run:

```
PowerShell

Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

What should put for `<VMName>`? Hyper-V? I believe I need to enable nested Virtualization...however, I have a VM running on my machine already for my job so nested virtualization must already be enabled, right?? It's called **"VMware Horizon Client"** but I'm not sure if that's helpful. Please let me know if you need more information and how I can generate it for you.

From reading other questions on this issue, I thought perhaps running **bcdedit /v** might help so below you'll find the output:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume4
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {af40e028-cd0f-11ea-b84f-850cbed154de}
resumeobject            {af40e027-cd0f-11ea-b84f-850cbed154de}
displayorder            {af40e028-cd0f-11ea-b84f-850cbed154de}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 0

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {af40e028-cd0f-11ea-b84f-850cbed154de}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {af40e029-cd0f-11ea-b84f-850cbed154de}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {af40e027-cd0f-11ea-b84f-850cbed154de}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

Comment: If you have a VM already running on your machine, chances are your machine is not itself a VM and you don't have to enable nested virtualization

Comment: Haha, yes you have a point there!  Do you have any suggestions as to how I can either address this error code directly so I can set up Ubuntu WSL? Or ideas on how I can investigate further?  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of which optional Windows features you have installed, making sure, to show the installation status of Virtual Machine Platform. Please provide this required necessary vital information by editing your question instead of submitting comment. By the way Windows 10 Home, is incapable of installing and activating Hyper-V, it seems you are confused by what exactly is required to enable WSL2 on Windows 10. What version of VMWare Workstation do you have installed on your machine?

Comment: "What should put for <VMName>? Hyper-V?" - Nothing; The command isn't applicable to your machine, since you are not running Windows within a Hyper-V VM, the command shouldn't be ran at all. "so nested virtualization must already be enabled, right??" - Nested virtualization and hardware virtualization are two entirely different beasts. While you can't have nested virtualization without hardware virilization you can have hardware vitalization without nested virtualization.

Comment: @squillman - Windows 10 Home absolutely does not support Hyper-V, it does support, the necessary optional Windows features required for WSL. **Hyper-V isn’t one of those requirements.**

Comment: Understood. I was mixing "WSL is supported" with "Install Hyper-V" without using my brain...